# FadeIn and FadeOut repeats when try to fade out

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

This is probably something ease to fix and I have missed some obvious but can't really find what it is.

When I click on backgroundcover I want the div songtitle fadeIn over backgroundcover, it works just fine but when I click on div songtitle I want songtitle to fadeOut and here is were the problems start.

I have tried a few different ways to come arround this but without success. The problem is, when I click songtitle div it fades out as it should but half a second later it fadeIn again and i can't come arround this.

```
$(".backgroundcover").click(function() { 
    $(".songtitle").fadeIn("fast");
});

$(".songtitle").click(function() { 
    $(".songtitle").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

And if I change it to this it works just fine, BUT only one time, so I can only fadeIn the div once!

```
$(".backgroundcover").click(function() { 
    $(".songtitle").fadeIn("fast");
});

$(".songtitle").click(function() { 
    $(".songtitle").fadeOut({opacity : 0}, 400);
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="backgroundcover">
    <div class="songtitle"><a href="#">Hejsan testar</a>Destiny's child - Unknown</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the equivalent HTML. Perhaps there's an issue with that?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really cache the `$(".songtitle")` selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that the handler for the `.songtitle` click event allows the event to bubble up to it's parent, which causes the `.backgroundcover` handler to be invoked as well (which fades the text back in).

As you're using jQuery, you can prevent the event propagation by returning `false` from the handler:

```
$(".songtitle").click(function() { 
    $(".songtitle").fadeOut({opacity : 0}, 400);
    return false;
});
```

You can see a [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/ef6YE/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The return false did it!